# Wallpaper app in Android studio Runtime Error

Tags: java, android

I am new developer.I created the wallpaper app. However, when I run the application, I get an error. But the application does not show any errors. I checked all the steps and could not find it.There is an error in java 55. and 17. line I guess that's what it looks like in logcat.I don't understand the problem.This is the class that gave the error. Are there any errors in the codes?

Below are the implementions i use.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0
```

This is my code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<ImageModel> wallpaperlist;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageModel> wallpaperlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.wallpaperlist = wallpaperlist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent browswerintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        browswerintent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.pexels.com/"));
                        browswerintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(browswerintent);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        Glide.with(context).load(wallpaperlist.get(position).getSrc().getPortrait()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,setwallpaper.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",wallpaperlist.get(position).getSrc().getPortrait());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wallpaperlist.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        }
    }
}
```

Console log

```
2021-08-17 10:21:18.850 12748-12748/com.heragamestudio.a4k_hdlivewallpaper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wallpaper, PID: 12748
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:768)
        at com.wallpaper.Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Adapter.java:55)
        at com.wallpaper.Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Adapter.java:17)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
2021-08-17 10:21:18.850 12748-12748/com.wallpaper E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Item_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="208dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/iamge"
                android:background="@drawable/imageviewbg"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop">

            </ImageView>



        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/textviewbg"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Photo"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:drawableTint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24" />


        </LinearLayout>









    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please share your console log ?

Comment: Hello, i share console log.

Comment: can you post `R.layout.item_layout` XML file?

Comment: Have you checked (via debugger or a simple log statement) that `holder.imageView` is not null before line 55? Maybe that view is not found in the `ViewHolder` constructor.

Comment: I checked. but no problem is seen.

Comment: @Mr.Çınar: how did you check? It's obviously null. Did you read snachmsms answer below? It contains the solution.

Comment: My problem is solved. I missed a typo.Thank you to everyone who supports.

Answer (score 1):

your stacktrace is suggesting that your `imageView` is `null`, there is an NPE in Glide-related code in `into` method (which takes this `imageView` as argument)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:768)
```

ensure that your inflated list item contains `ImageView` with `R.id.image` id

```
imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

edit: after XML added to question: your `ImageView` have `android:id="@+id/iamge"` id - IAMGE not IMAGE. so above `findViewById` found nothing, `imageView` will stay `null` after this method execution

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!